# Solving TypeError when concatenating a string

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I assigned these variables:

```
x = "1"
name = str(input("Enter Name  :"))
gender = str(input("Enter Gender (M/F)  :")).lower
year = int(input("Enter Year of Birth  :"))   
postcode = str(input("Enter Postcode  :"))
```

Then I got I got a part of the string postcode.

```
partCode = postcode[0:3]
```

Then I converted the year in to a string.

```
birthYear = str(year)
```

After, I tried concatenating all the strings:

```
username = name + birthYear + gender + partCode + x
```

And I receive this error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "builtin_function_or_method") to str
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Why are you converting `year` to an `int` if you are just going to convert it back to a `str` in the first place? None of the calls to `str` are necessary, because `input` already returns a `str`.

Comment: As for your question, `lower` is a method, not a lowercase version of the original string. You need to call it: `gender = input(...).lower()`.

Comment: in addition to advise from @chepner, use string-formatting - e.g. f-strings or str.format() method, not concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The above error is because `gender` is not a string

replace

```
gender = str(input("Enter Gender (M/F)  :")).lower
```

with

```
gender = str(input("Enter Gender (M/F)  :")).lower()
```

Comment: Thanks! I realised what was wrong. You have been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
x = "1"
name = str(input("Enter Name  :"))
gender = str(input("Enter Gender (M/F)  :")).lower()
year = int(input("Enter Year of Birth  :"))   
postcode = str(input("Enter Postcode  :"))

partCode = postcode[0:3]
birthYear = str(year)
username = name + birthYear + gender + partCode + x
```

Comment: Thanks! I realised the error and you have been really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert any of the input variables their all read in as `str`.

This will do

```
x = "1"
name = str(input("Enter Name  :"))
gender = str(input("Enter Gender (M/F)  :")).lower()
year = str(input("Enter Year of Birth  :"))   
postcode = str(input("Enter Postcode  :"))
```

The issue is you didn't have `()` for the `lower` function so your `gender` variable was `<built-in method lower of str object at 0x7fb7152ffc38>`. That should explain your error